# Update and store previous value in another column

Tags: postgresql

I need to add to price, but also store the existing price in another column.

My table 'veges' has 3 columns

item-----price-----old_price

I can update column 'price' fine, but getting a headache trying to store the old value in 'old_price'

This statement does the update, ideally it would also update the old_price column, but I'm having difficulty doing that.

```
$sql = 'update veges set price = price + ? where item = ?';
    $v = array($add, $item);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($v);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign it:

```
update veges
   set price = price + 10, 
       old_price = price
where item = 42;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2a1cc9fb2e8cd5005a1b88b0f902ed49)

Comment: Thanks, now why isn't that in the blooming tutorial I spent 2 hours wading through :-(, I'll accept answer when it lets me in a few minutes.

Comment: It's right here [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) "*The expression can use the old values of this and other columns in the table*"